# Flutter socket io doesn't connect to node js socket io server port 3000

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets

> NODE JS SERVER

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected");
  /* console.log(socket) */
  socket.on("msg", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    
  });
  Cars.watch().on("change", () => {
    console.log("Something has changed");
    Cars.find()
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .then((items) => {
        console.log(items);
        io.emit("ucer", items);
      });
  });
  

  
});
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

> FLUTTER CLIENT SIDE

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeSocket();
  }

  void initializeSocket() {
    print('initializeSocket');
    
    IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket.connect();
    
  }
```

> When the initializeSocket function is run, the code execution without error while i was waiting for connection print in the terminal ,However print('initializeSocket') on the debug console.

[heroku node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRI7n.png)

[flutter sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BH1S.png)

Comment: change localhost to you server ip

Comment: `http://localhost:3000` to `http://youserverip:3000`

Comment: same i replaced http://localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:3000/ nothing change

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is same effect as localhost

Comment: which is your os? is it windows or linux

Comment: your ip may like 192.168 .*.* like that

Comment: check out image above .

Comment: may be 192.168.1.1  is gateway ip end with 1 mostly  check ipv4 ip

Comment: yes you are right yet even i change my ipv4 ip nothing change i think i'll try to deploy heroku and try to change url

Comment: yes that's it. . use

Answer (score 0):

**windows**

use this ipv4 address to instead of `localhost:3000` access in the mobile
[image]

**Linux**

[image]

Comment: i tried my ipv4 adress but no connection detected , however i deployed my node js app on heroku and trying to test and it's the same no connection in flutter app check out picture above .

Comment: if you are using windows .your firewall you turn off for testing purpose .or create inbound rule or outbound rule.